# Найти удалённый ответ

Tags: поддержка, удаление-вопросов, удаление-ответов

В последние полгода-год я писал очень хороший ответ, где перечислял полезные новичку и не только инструменты для работы с серверами, то ли на enSO, то ли на ruSO, не помню.

Дважды обыскал все свои ответы и вручную, и нормальным поиском по юзеру, ключевым словам и с `deleted:1`, совсем не могу его найти. Видимо, вопрос был удалён вместе с моим ответом.

Подскажите, есть ли способ его вернуть, чтобы, например, написать вопрос-ответ самому?

Answer (score 1):

Старая тема: [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/260198).

Сейчас можно посмотреть сообщения удалённые за последние `60` дней со страницы профиля.

Всё остальное можно посмотреть, если есть прямая ссылка на сообщение.